multiple image upload issue while editing images in codeigniter php
i have an image upload form, while adding the upload is working fine. Now my edit form looks like below:
                 <input type="hidden" name="pimage2old" value="<?=$val['pimage2']?>">
                      
                      <?php
                      $selectedDays = $val['days'];
$titles = explode('|', $val['title']);
$pimages = explode('|', $val['pimage2']);
$details = explode('|', $val['details']);
$notes = explode('|', $val['note']);
                      
                      ?>
                       <div class="col-md-12 position-relative" id="dayRows" >
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) : ?>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:1%;<?= ($i <= $selectedDays) ? '' : 'display:none;' ?>" id="day<?php echo $i; ?>Row">
            <div class="col-md-2 position-relative">
                <label class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold">Day <?php echo $i; ?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 position-relative">
                <label class="form-label" for="validationTooltip14">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="validationTooltip14" type="text" name="title[]" value="<?=$titles[$i-1]?>" onkeypress="return RestrictCommaSemicolon(event);"
    ondrop="return false;" onfocusout="checkComma(this);">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 position-relative">
                <label class="form-label" for="validationTooltip15">Image: <?php if($pimages[$i-1]){?><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/packages/<?=$pimages[$i-1]?>">View Image</a><?php } ?></label>
                <input class="form-control" id="validationTooltip15" type="file" name="pimage2[]" >
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 position-relative">
                <label class="form-label" for="validationTooltip16">Details</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="validationTooltip16" name="details[]" onkeypress="return RestrictCommaSemicolon(event);"
    ondrop="return false;" onfocusout="checkComma(this);"><?=$details[$i-1]?></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 position-relative">
                <label class="form-label" for="validationTooltip17">Note</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="validationTooltip17"  name="note[]" onkeypress="return RestrictCommaSemicolon(event);"
    ondrop="return false;" onfocusout="checkComma(this);"><?=$notes[$i-1]?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>

and my controller to handle images is like
              if (!empty($_FILES['pimage2']['name'])) {
    $config2['upload_path'] = './uploads/packages/';
    $config2['allowed_types'] = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload');

    $images = array();
    $filesCount = count($_FILES['pimage2']['name']);
    $oldImages = explode('|', $details['pimage2old']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
        if (!empty($_FILES['pimage2']['name'][$i])) {
            $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['size'][$i];

            $this->upload->initialize($config2);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
                $uploadData2 = $this->upload->data();
                $images[$i] = $uploadData2['file_name'];
            } else {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                var_dump($error);
                $images[$i] = '';
            }
        } else {
            $images[$i] = $oldImages[$i];
        }
    }

    // Concatenate the image names with a pipe separator
    $picture2 = implode('|', $images);
} else {
    $picture2 = $details['pimage2old'];
}

here the upload is not working, if i replace any specific image or add an image to a field where image is not there, its not happening, previous images are not replaced also, what could be the issue here, thanks in advance

Does your code work if you change the first image in your form? Because this line if (!empty($_FILES['pimage2']['name'][0])) only checks if the first image has been changed, so if you change any of the others but not the first, it'll keep the old images.

@Marleen yes, first image is changing

@Marleen i have made slight adjustments to the controller code, i have updated in question, can you check if thats ok

If you use if (!empty($_FILES['pimage2']['name'][0])) it'll only process the uploaded images if a new image was uploaded for the first field.
Your intention is probably to check if any images were uploaded, and if so process them all.
But with your form setup, $_FILES['pimage2']['name'] will always have a value (if no images were uploaded this'll contain an array with empty strings) so if (!empty($_FILES['pimage2']['name'])) will always return true. So there's no easy way to check if any images were uploaded unless you loop through the $_FILES array and check them one by one.
And since you're already doing that in the inner loop with if (!empty($_FILES['pimage2']['name'][$i])), I would suggest removing the outer if altogether:
$config2['upload_path'] = './uploads/packages/';
$config2['allowed_types'] = '*';

$this->load->library('upload');

$images = array();
$filesCount = count($_FILES['pimage2']['name']);
$oldImages = explode('|', $details['pimage2old']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
    if (!empty($_FILES['pimage2']['name'][$i])) {
        $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['pimage2']['size'][$i];

        $this->upload->initialize($config2);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
            $uploadData2 = $this->upload->data();
            $images[$i] = $uploadData2['file_name'];
        } else {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            var_dump($error);
            $images[$i] = '';
        }
    } else {
        $images[$i] = $oldImages[$i];
    }
}

// Concatenate the image names with a pipe separator
$picture2 = implode('|', $images);

